# How do you get VS Code to keep focus on the same line after a return?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Background:** I like to have some space at the bottom of my code while I am coding, so I am not typing at the bottom of the screen all the time. This was a problem with Eclipse, but with VS Code you can now scroll up past your lines.

**Problem:** Here is my dilemma, when I am typing and go to the next line, VSCode moves my cursor to the next line. This is all fine and dandy, until it starts gets to the bottom, and I have to scroll up to keep my code from the bottom of my screen. This gets bothersome.

**Question:** When you get to the second to last line in your code, your cursor STAYS IN THE SAME SPOT, and the code above, moves up. I am not sure if it is a setting, or maybe you are unable to do so, but is there a way to make that a default? I only want my screen to move when I manually do so.

Comment: Use the `Insert Line Above` keyboard shortcut instead. For me it is, Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Comment: @gonzo is there a way to make my Enter key default to 'insert line above'?

Comment: Give this page a read. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings You might have to remove the Enter binding from other shortcuts.